# How to install GPU Ocelot in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, gpu, ocelot

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I wish to install [GPU Ocelot](http://gpuocelot.gatech.edu/about/) (an open-source dynamic JIT compilation framework for GPU compute applications) in it. I have searched for suitable Ocelot versions but I could not find any.

Is there any way to install GPU Ocelot in my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

**Installation**

If `git` is not installed, install it:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git
```

Checkout Ocelot from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/gtcasl/gpuocelot.git
```

Optionally: Install `boost`

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Optionally: Install compiler tools

```
sudo apt-get install flex bison g++ scons
```

Enter the `gpuocelot/ocelot` directory

```
cd gpuocelot/ocelot
```

Run the `build` script.

```
sudo ./build.py --install
```

This will install the Ocelot development headers and libraries:

```
libocelot.so
```

Create the necessary system links to the Ocelot library so the dynamic linker will find it:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

This library can be used to access the tools within ocelot or linked against a CUDA application compiled with NVCC to emulate a CUDA device.

Alternatively, there is a new utility, `OcelotConfig` that is intended simply the process of linking against Ocelot.

To link a program against Ocelot:

```
g++ -o my_program my_program.o OcelotConfig -l
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/gtcasl/gpuocelot/wiki/Installation) link for more details.